# AngularJS Directive with Select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, binding

I have a problem using angular 1.6.5 and tried everything but without any noticeable progress...

I made a directive that implement the HTML `SELECT` tag, the component seems to work until I try to get the entire object in `option value` attribute instead of a single value or ID.
I can output the text of the option tag both as a property of the object or trough a function the return some string.

Here is a complete fiddle with the component and the problem.
There are 3 examples:

1. The 1st one seems to work correctly, it print the correct text and return the correct value
2. The 2nd: do not work, I'd like to set to the model the entire OBJECT selected and not a property
3. The 3rd: do not work, I'd like to set to the model the entire OBJECT selected and not a property but it print correctly the text from a function in parent controller.

How can I change my component that it can return both a property (like ID) both the entire object (JSON format is good)?

```js
angular.module("myApp", ['customDrop']).controller("TestController", ['$scope', function($scope) {
  var ITEM_SELECTED = {
    ID: 3,
    VALUE: "VALUE3"
  };
  $scope.LIST = [{
      ID: 1,
      VALUE: "VALUE1"
    },
    {
      ID: 2,
      VALUE: "VALUE2"
    },
    ITEM_SELECTED,
  ];

  $scope.OBJ = {
    LOTTO1: ITEM_SELECTED,
    LOTTO2: ITEM_SELECTED,
    LOTTO3: ITEM_SELECTED

  };

  $scope.getCompleteValue = function(obj) {
    return obj.ID + " - " + obj.VALUE;
  }
}]);

angular.module('customDrop', []).directive('customDrop', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      dropid: '@',
      dropvalue: '&',
      list: '=',
      ngModel: '='
    },
    require: 'ngModel',
    template: '<select class="drop" ng-model="ngModel">' +
      '<option ng-repeat="val in list" value="{{getId(val)}}">{{getValue(val)}}</option>' +
      '</select>',
    controller: ['$scope', '$parse', '$timeout',
      function($scope, $parse, $timeout) {
        $scope.getId = function(obj) {
          return obj[$scope.dropid];
        }

        // Can print text option as proerty of through function in parent scope.
        $scope.getValue = function(obj) {
          return !angular.isFunction($scope.dropvalue(obj)) ?
            $scope.dropvalue(obj) :
            $parse($scope.dropvalue(obj))(obj);
        }
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

```css
.drop {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="TestController">
  <strong>Simple Text Property (drop id intended to return the ID): (working)</strong><br>
  <custom-drop dropvalue="VALUE" dropid="ID" list="LIST" ng-model="OBJ.LOTTO1"></custom-drop><br> Selected Value: {{OBJ.LOTTO1}}
  <br><br><br>
  <!-- using property as dropValue -->
  <strong>Simple Text Property (drop id intended to return an object): (not working)</strong><br>
  <custom-drop dropvalue="VALUE" dropid="" list="LIST" ng-model="OBJ.LOTTO2"></custom-drop><br> Selected Value: {{OBJ.LOTTO2}}
  <br><br><br>
  <!-- using function as dropValue -->
  <strong>Function Text Property: (not working)</strong><br>
  <custom-drop dropvalue="getCompleteValue" dropid="" list="LIST" ng-model="OBJ.LOTTO3"></custom-drop><br> Selected Value: {{OBJ.LOTTO3}}
</div>
```

Comment: becide your question, so many issues here -  do not even include jquery, prefer component, do not use additional ngModel, do not use method in templates, prefer ng-options... Finally - do not write such component at all - it will take you age to make it viable. (I.e. in this implementation  you can not add validator to field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set to the model the entire OBJECT selected you have to modify your `getId()` method to return the object in case `$scope.dropid` was not passed through the bindings (since this method is used to generate the value of the `option`). Also I recommend using [`ngOptions`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) to generate the list of `option` elements. See the snippet below:

```js
angular.module("myApp", ['customDrop']).controller("TestController", ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    var ITEM_SELECTED = {
        ID: 3,
        VALUE: "VALUE3"
    };
    $scope.LIST = [{
        ID: 1,
        VALUE: "VALUE1"
    },
        {
            ID: 2,
            VALUE: "VALUE2"
        },
        ITEM_SELECTED,
    ];

    $scope.OBJ = {
        LOTTO1: ITEM_SELECTED.ID,
        LOTTO2: ITEM_SELECTED,
        LOTTO3: ITEM_SELECTED

    };

    $scope.getCompleteValue = function (obj) {
        return obj.ID + " - " + obj.VALUE;
    }
}]);

angular.module('customDrop', []).directive('customDrop', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            dropid: '@',
            dropvalue: '&',
            list: '<',
            ngModel: '='
        },
        require: 'ngModel',
        template: '<select class="drop" ng-model="ngModel" ng-options="getModelValue(val) as getOptionText(val) for val in list"></select>',
        controller: ['$scope', '$parse',
            function ($scope, $parse) {
                $scope.getModelValue = function (obj) {
                    return !!$scope.dropid ? obj[$scope.dropid] : obj;
                };

                $scope.getOptionText = function (obj) {
                    return !angular.isFunction($scope.dropvalue(obj)) ?
                        $scope.dropvalue(obj) :
                        $parse($scope.dropvalue(obj))(obj);
                }
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

```css
.drop {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="TestController">
  <strong>Simple Text Property (drop id intended to return the ID): </strong><br>
  <custom-drop dropvalue="VALUE" dropid="ID" list="LIST" ng-model="OBJ.LOTTO1"></custom-drop><br> Selected Value: {{OBJ.LOTTO1}}
  <br><br><br>
  <!-- using property as dropValue -->
  <strong>Simple Text Property (drop id intended to return an object): </strong><br>
  <custom-drop dropvalue="VALUE" dropid="" list="LIST" ng-model="OBJ.LOTTO2"></custom-drop><br> Selected Value: {{OBJ.LOTTO2}}
  <br><br><br>
  <!-- using function as dropValue -->
  <strong>Function Text Property: </strong><br>
  <custom-drop dropvalue="getCompleteValue" dropid="" list="LIST" ng-model="OBJ.LOTTO3"></custom-drop><br> Selected Value: {{OBJ.LOTTO3}}
</div>
```